# Are sessions/cookies required for a website with no registered users?

Tags: web, session-cookies

First time making a webapp, and to start out it is going to be anonymous. Will I need some kind of sessions or cookies to monitor users? For example, if someone is uploading too many files/spamming within a certain time period I want to temp disallow this, but not based on IP because IP bans can affect public places like schools and libraries which is bad if it is only one person.

Comment: what technology are you using?

Comment: not needed . you use them as per your needs . if u get a doubt 'do i need it' which means u can do it without that for that problem

Comment: Flask for the web framework, mostly JS on the frontend, I will probably be deploying to a traditional server running nginx or something, no cloud services or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to require login if you want a robust way to preventing spam or uploading too many files. Using cookies or session is not very good since all the user has to do to get around it is deleting the cookie issued by your site.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective way to stop spammers by applying limits like this.

Protection with IP, as you noticed, doesn't work, because IP addresses are often shared. But neither cookies (and sessions, which are based on cookies) are effective, because they can be deleted very easily.

Instead, you may want to check at the content users create. This all depends on the kind of service you are creating, but some things to consider are:

- Spammers usually post the same content many times, with slight variations. For example, they post the same text, the same pictures, etc.
- Most spam posts include links.

Some effective ways to fight spam may include:

- Require completing a CAPTCHA before posting anything. This will block bots, but annoy humans a bit.
- Force users to authenticate somehow. Thankfully, in 2014 we have single sign-on like Facebook, Google, etc (and hardly anybody in the world doesn't have an account there)
- Try with solutions like [Akismet](http://akismet.com)